# Can ridge regression be used to solve overdetermined equations?

Tags: python, regression, linear-algebra, equation, least-squares

There is no unique solution for overdetermined equations, but the least squares method can be used to obtain approximate solutions. I learned that ridge regression is an optimized least squares method that can better fit ill-conditioned data. After searching, I did not find any examples of using ridge regression to solve overdetermined equations. So I think it’s either too simple to be discussed, or there are some restrictions and it’s infeasible to do so. I'm not sure what the reason is.

In addition, in Python, the least squares method can be used to solve overdetermined equations by simply calling the numpy.linalg.lstsq() method. So is there a similar method of ridge regression to solve overdetermined equations?

Thx!

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve you could also use lasso regression. Ridge regression is going to shrink the values of your parameters, but they will only reach 0 (aka be discarded from the model) if your budget parameter is set to 0. Lasso on the other hand is going to shrink some parameters to 0 without the budget set to 0.

Comment: I should also add when the budget parameter is set to 0 all of your model will always predict 0 (the model is going to reduce to y=0)

Comment: You should also know that there are several other ways to tackle this problem, for example you could manually make a selection of which variables are the most impactful for your model, you could also do that programatically with forward selection and stepwise selection, you could reduce your dimension with pricipal component regression

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! I looked into [ridge regressor in Sklearn module](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html), and found nothing related with solving a system of equations. Did I look at a wrong place?

Comment: I think it's an issue of how you word problem. From what I understand you have more variables than you have data points, all the methods I listed (except PCR) are used to make variable selection which would solve your issue, but it's not specifically desogned to do so

Comment: PCR on the other hand is specificaly designed to reduce the dimension of your problem

Comment: What I want to do is finding an approximate solution for a system of overdetermined equations, instead of reducing dimensionality of unknowns.

Comment: I didn't understand your problem correctly, so you have a system of linear equations that you are trying to solve and the system is overdetermined

Comment: In that case ridge regression will not help you, it's a linear algebra problem not a statistical problem

Answer (score 0):

[Ridge Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_regression) basically adds a prior on the data.

The model is given by $ \arg\min_{x} \frac{1}{2} {\left| A x - y \right|}*{2}^{2} + {\left| x \right|}*{2}^{2} $:

[image]

You may interpret it as (Which are different sides of the same coin):

1. You have a prior of the distribution of $ x $ to be Gaussian.
2. You know the solution should be damped to make $ x $ close to zero.